# Python Get index of Tuple with using endswith

Tags: gae-python27

Is there a to give me the index of the tuple when I use `endswith` function.

eg:

```
lst = ('jpg','mp4','mp3')
b = "filemp4"
```

If I use `b.endswith(lst)`, this give me `True` or `false`. 
but I need to find the index of '`lst`' that match's the the string provided in '`b`'

Comment: I don't see this in the docs. It could be an improvement, but it would break the current paradigmm since size index 0 would register as False. Maybe there could be a *endswithreturnindex* method (or something else).